# Convergence of a series with $k^{\rm th}$ root

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

How can I show that the series
$$
\sum_{k=1}^\infty \big(\sqrt[k]{a}-1\big)^k,
$$
where $a>0$.

Thank you for help.

Comment: Whenever there is a $k$ in the base and exponent, try $k$-th root test.

Comment: Eventually, $|\root k \of a -1|<1/2$.

Answer (score 2):

We have

$$\left(|a^{1/k}-1|\right)^k=\left(|\exp\left(\frac 1 k\log a\right)-1|\right)^k\sim_\infty\left(\frac{|\log a|}{k}\right)^k<\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^k\quad\text{for large $k$}$$
so the given series is absolutely convergent by comparison with geometric convergent series $\displaystyle\sum_k \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^k$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that 
$$
\sqrt[k]{a}-1=\mathrm{e}^{\ln a/k}-\mathrm{e}^0=\frac{\ln a}{k}\mathrm{e}^\vartheta,
$$
for some $\vartheta\in (0,\ln a/k)$. Clearly $\mathrm{e}^\vartheta\le M=\max\{1,a\}$.
Thus
$$
|\sqrt[k]{a}-1|\le M\frac{\ln a}{k},
$$
and finally
$$
|\sqrt[k]{a}-1|^k\le \frac{c^k}{k^k},
$$
for some $c>0$, etc.

Answer (score 0):

We apply [Ratio Test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test):
$$
\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty} \left(\left|\big(\sqrt[k]{a}-1\big)^k\right|\right)^{1/k}=\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty} \left|\sqrt[k]{a}-1\right|=0<1
$$
so the given series is absolutely convergent.